# CSS Rounded corners Top Left corner not rounding. Ideas?

Tags: html, css, rounded-corners

Ok I am attempting to round my corners via CSS so I can drop a bunch of images from an older style template I am remastering for a client. The idea is use something that can fail gracefully. Which I think it would generally speaking. However in this case it appears the the top left corner of one of the elements is not rounding like the rest of the same element is on its other corners. I am using a class to pass this to elements and this class works on all the other elements flawlessly its just this one element..

content_wrap to be more specific. Its the element that all the other elements reside in.
Here is a jsfiddle version of it.

http://jsfiddle.net/8qZze/

anyone have any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `overflow:hidden` to the `#content_wrap` to stop anything from overlapping the corners from inside. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/8qZze/1/

```
#content_wrap{
    overflow: hidden
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I removed the ".white" rule and it worked, the child "content_left" has a rectangular shape ant it goes over the rounded corner of "content_wrap", try to specify some margin to leave more space for the rounded corner and everything will be fine.

Or try tw16's advice with overflow (forgot about it :) )